# how can select element in mobile with touch event like mouse event

Tags: javascript, html

i have code fore time table for select the element of day it is working 
in laptope divice with mouse event
but in touch event in mobile not working 
and i have another problem icon for close form onclick in desktop divice
work but ontouch for mobile note work

```
 ontouchstart="alert();" // work true; in mobile
 ontouchstart="close();" // not working false; in mobile
 onclick="close();" // work true; in desktop
 close();//custom function
```

thanks and sorry for my english

```
var lundi = mytr[1].children, mardi = mytr[2].children, mercredi = 
mytr[3].children,jeudi = mytr[4].children;
var l=1,m1=1,m2=1,j=1,v=1,s=1,aux;
flag = true;
if(m1 && m2 && j && v && s){
lundi[i].addEventListener('mousedown',function(event) {
down =true;
l=false;
HeurDebut = this.cellIndex;          
});
lundi[i].addEventListener('mousemove',function(event) {
if (flag && down && m1 && m2 && j && v && s){
    this.classList.add(color);
    jour  = "Lundi";
    Njour = 1;
}
});
lundi[i].addEventListener('mouseup',function(event) {
flag = false;
HeurFin = this.cellIndex;
if(retemp){
    sendTemp(HeurDebut,HeurFin,jour,Njour);
    retemp = false; 
 }
 form.style.display ="block";          
});
}
//for mobile
flag = true;
if(m1 && m2 && j && v && s){
lundi[i].addEventListener('touchstart',function(event) {
down =true;
l=false;
HeurDebut = this.cellIndex;  
});
lundi[i].addEventListener('touchmove',function(event) {
if (flag && down && m1 && m2 && j && v && s){
    this.classList.add(color);
    jour  = "Lundi";
    Njour = 1;
} 
});
lundi[i].addEventListener('touchend',function(event) {

flag = false;
HeurFin = this.cellIndex;
if(retemp){
    sendTemp(HeurDebut,HeurFin,jour,Njour);
    retemp = false;     
 }
 form.style.display ="block";
});
}
```

Comment: the standard mouse events also work on touch devices. you can just use "click" or "mousedown" and it will work on touch and touchstart too.

Comment: no i use mousedown it  works in desktop but ni mobile not